# Using MSBuild on a Machine without Visual Studio

Tags: c#, msbuild

I have a blank machine that I am using for Continuous Integration.

I am able to download the project (.sln) files locally to the c drive, then I am trying to run the msbuild once the download is complete, but the build fails.

I know I can download Visual Studio and have this working because I did this on my local machine, but I need to know how or what do I need to download and install on the blank machine just to run the MSBuild successfully with out Visual Studio.

The error is:

> MSBUILD : error MSB1025: An internal failure occurred while running MSBuild. System.NotSupportedException: The given path's format is not supported.

Comment: I am running it again, so I give that, but would you know what I need to download just for the MSBuild to work?

Comment: If you're compiling, you probably have what you need.  You are probably missing something in your solution, like a referenced dll, that is causing the build to fail.

Comment: "The build fails" is a meaningless problem description. In what way does it "fail"? Without that information, this question can't be answered. Please be specific when you ask questions here. If something fails, tell us what "failure" means, how you know it failed, and any information you have about that failure such as error messages. Without it, we can't help you.

Comment: I dont think I am compiling this is the error: MSBUILD : error MSB1025: An internal failure occurred while running MSBuild.
System.NotSupportedException: The given path's format is not supported.

Comment: What is the command you're using to execute the build?

Comment: I am also getting MSB4014 error

Comment: I running this command /t:Rebuild /p:Platform="Any CPU" /p:Configuration=DEV with the project solution path, but a thing about this is that on my development enviornment where Visual STudio is installed, I set up Continuous Integration doing the samething download code and building and it works. I am on a new machine and trying to do the same without visual studio being installed

Comment: In your error it says the path is not supported, what is the path you're giving to msbuild?  Is it quoted?

Comment: System.NotSupportedException: The given path's format is not supported.
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)

Comment: at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
   at Microsoft.Build.Construction.SolutionParser.GetSolutionFileMajorVersion(String solutionFile)
   at Microsoft.Build.Execution.ProjectInstance.LoadSolutionForBuild(String projectFile, PropertyDictionary`1 globalPropertiesInstances, String toolsVersion, BuildParameters buildParameters, ILoggingService loggingService, BuildEventContext projectBuildEventContext, Boolean isExplicitlyLoaded)

Comment: i am geting theis error above error MSB4014: The Build stopped unexpectedly becaiuse of an internal error